# How to make Apple keyboard QuickPath/slide remember my name?

Tags: keyboard

I've been using the stock keyboard since always and try to use the Quickpath/slide/swype feature that come built-in.

I, however, never managed to make it remember my last name nor the one from my wife. Can't find anything in the settings, nor adding a shortcut, nor clicking on the suggestion when I tap character by character seems to help.

Am I missing something or did Apple really did not develop this feature?

Thanks for your help